# What does filter(loaded =>!loaded) do?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs

This is from [this Article](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2017/08/easily-ensure-that-data-is-loaded-with.html). What does the `filter(loaded => !loaded)` do? I don't see that variable defined anywhere.

I understand what the purpose of the method it, just not that particular line.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    // 1
    const isLoaded$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getUsers)
      .map(users => users.length > 0);

    // 2
    isLoaded$
      .take(1)
      .filter(loaded => !loaded)  // here
      .map(() => new user.LoadAllAction())
      .subscribe(this.store);

    // 3
    return isLoaded$
      .take(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loaded is defined in the function passed to `filter`:

```
filter(loaded => !loaded)
```

is essentially the same as

```
filter(function(loaded) {return !loaded});
```

As far as what it does, it filters out elements that are falsey.

Comment: @mtyson sure, no problem! :-)

Comment: any opinion why the author chose to do a `.take(1)` at the end instead of `unsubscribe()`?